# How to rectify this program?

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

This is a program to display a pie chart. I also have a button. But the program I have written, creates two separate frames and one frame is for the pie chart and the other is for the button. How do I put both button and pie chart on the same frame?? Can you please rectify my program.

```
import java.awt.*;

import org.jfree.chart.*;

import org.jfree.chart.title.*;

import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;

import org.jfree.ui.*;

import java.io.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.filechooser.*;

public class Pie{

 public static void getFile(File f)
{

    System.out.println("File is: "+f.getName());

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{

   JPanel panel=new JPanel();

    panel.setLayout(null);

    JButton b=new JButton("Open File");

    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener()

 {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

  {

        JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();

        int ret = chooser.showDialog(null, "Open file");

        if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)

        {

        File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();

        getFile(file);

        }

       }

    }
);
       b.setBounds(50,40,100,35);

       panel.add(b);

    DefaultPieDataset pieDataset = new DefaultPieDataset();


  ieDataset.setValue("A", new Integer(10));

  pieDataset.setValue("B", new Integer(20));

  pieDataset.setValue("C", new Integer(30));

  pieDataset.setValue("D", new Integer(10));

  pieDataset.setValue("E", new Integer(20));

  pieDataset.setValue("F", new Integer(10));

  FreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart("Pie Chart using JFreeChart", pieDataset, true,true,true);

  ChartFrame frame1=new ChartFrame("Pie Chart",chart);

  frame1.add(panel);

  frame1.setVisible(true);

  frame1.setSize(600,600);

 }

}
```

Comment: Explain this `ChartFrame frame1=new ChartFrame("Pie Chart",chart);`. I think you are actually creating two frames...

Comment: The first argument is the title and the second is the JFreeChart obejct.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use absolute layout unless it is really necessary. Rely on layout managers, pref/min/max size and constraints to size and position components. This also means that you should not call setBounds/setSize/setLocation on components, let the layout manager do this for you.
2. Init the UI from the EDT (Event dispatching tread)
3. You don't do anything with your FileChooser currently
4. Try to avoid `static` and instead use `new Something()`
5. Don't use `new Integer()` but rather use `Integer.valueOf()` (and this is valid for all the primitive wrapping classes, Boolean, Short, Long, ...)

I am not sure how you get two frames, but I got your code working by modifying it this way.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;

public class Pie {

    private static void initUI() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        final JButton b = new JButton("Open File");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                int ret = chooser.showDialog(b, "Open file");
                if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                    // Don't know what you want to do
                }
            }

        });
        panel.add(b);
        DefaultPieDataset pieDataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
        pieDataset.setValue("A", Integer.valueOf(10));
        pieDataset.setValue("B", Integer.valueOf(20));
        pieDataset.setValue("C", Integer.valueOf(30));
        pieDataset.setValue("D", Integer.valueOf(10));
        pieDataset.setValue("E", Integer.valueOf(20));
        pieDataset.setValue("F", Integer.valueOf(10));
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart("Pie Chart using JFreeChart", pieDataset, true, true, true);
        JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        // chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        frame1.getContentPane().add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame1.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame1.pack();
        frame1.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm trying to get a hang of the program. what i actually need is a frame in which i'm able to input a text file[say that the input text file has a set of integer values]. Read the text file and plot a line graph.

Comment: @user1430719, ok so you'll have to code that in the action listener or probably better wrap all this is a class that extends `AbstractAction` and pass that class to the constructor of the `JButton`

Answer (score 1):

There is a class called `ChartPanel`. It is a sub class of `JPanel` class.

```
JPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
```

Then you can add this panel to the frame. hope this helps........

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
  ChartFrame frame1=new ChartFrame("Pie Chart",chart);
```

with

```
   panel.add(chart)
```

Kindly let me know the result

Comment: I get this error message "The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (JFreeChart)"

Comment: then dont add button in panel by writing panel.add(b). Add button directly into frame by frame1.add(b).

Comment: Got it! Thank you. I have another doubt. How do I layout the components on the frame? The button appears right on top of the pie chart. I want the button and pie chart side by side.

Comment: you can set layout to flowlayout.